# Is there a way to make Powershell use forward slashes instead of backslashes for path autocompletion?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Lately I have been using the `wsl` command to run Linux (Ubuntu) binaries and commands within powershell.

For instance:

```
ls | wsl grep 'log'
```

I was trying to use vim to open a file named `.htaccess` but I didn't want to type the full name of the file. So instead I just typed `wsl vim .ht` and pressed tab to have powershell autocomplete the path. This autocompleted to `wsl vim .\.htaccess` which seemed fine but when I pressed enter, vim opened a new file named `..htaccess` (notice the additional period). That's when I realized that it was using the Windows' directory separator of backslash instead of forward slash. Presumably the backslash just escaped the period which is why in vim it was trying to create a new file named `..htaccess`.

I was wondering if there is any way to tweak powershell so that it uses forward slashes for path autocompletion instead of backslash. I know that lately Windows understands and translates forward slashes.

For example, this command works in powershell:

```
cd C:/Windows
```

Even though Windows uses backslash, this command worked and brought me to `C:\Windows`. So is there a way to make autocompletion use forward slash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I try to avoid "negative answers", but sometimes there's not much of a choice.  At present, I can't think of any good way to do this.  There was a Github [issue/feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/2219) for this earlier this year, and the PowerShell PSReadLine team replied with it being "As designed".

Just in case, though, I looked through the `Get-PSReadLineOption` options that are available, but there's no option for the path separator in there.

There's `[IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar`, but as a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784419/11810933) points out, it's read-only.

In considering possible alternatives, I couldn't come up with much:

- There might be a way to wrap a PowerShell function around your `wsl` call in a generic enough way that it could handle different commands.  The function would need to parse out the arguments and run a `wslpath` command around any paths.

  The `wslpath` command is installed by default in some WSL distributions (Ubuntu, at least) and can be installed on others via the [wslu](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu) package.

  E.g. `wslpath "C:\\"` returns `/mnt/c`

  But then we also get into double-backslash quoting issues, etc.  Ultimately, I dismissed this as too hacky and likely to be very "fragile".
- I believe you could handle this in a .NET `ArgumentCompleter` for the `wsl` command.  I've [written one](https://github.com/NotTheDr01ds/WSLTabCompletion) that handles the various flags for the WSL command that you are welcome to use as a base.

  I'm just not sure how difficult it would be to re-write the completer for files/directories, but I have a feeling it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Reading the linked Github issue comment, the answer is not exactly what this answer suggests; more precisely, as of now (Oct. 13th, 2022) there is no PS dev team answer for "can we have / as separator for PS on Windows" question.

Comment: @Joël Hmm - The statement from the OP of that Github issue was, *"Today when using tab-completion the forward slash is converted to slash."*  Then in [this comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/2219#issuecomment-779408970) the Microsoft team-member said, *"Those behavior are by design ..."*  They then go on to say that *on Linux*, it will use the forward slash, but not on Windows.  The Microsoft employee then closed the issue as completed.